# font Awesome not working in laravel/dompdf

Tags: laravel, font-awesome

I'm trying to use font awesome in **dompdf/laravel** but no matter what I try the icons don't show up, I've seen a bunch threads with similar or the same issue and their answers don't work for me. In my project I'm using **vue.js** for everything except the pdf where as far as I know I can only use a blade.

I've added this to the top of my HTML blade file

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"/>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{!! url('css/pdf.css') !!}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
     <header></header>
     <main></main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Still no luck, the icons show up as question marks (?)

How can I fix this?

Comment: create a minimal reproducible problem where you are actually trying to put an icon in a file. You could try to import the stylesheet locally.

Comment: @Flame I try like this `<p class="stars"><span class="fa fa-star"></span></p>` and it just shows a question mark instead

Comment: @Nancy Did problem solve or still facing error?

Comment: @UdhavSarvaiya Still facing this error, I tried the answers below without any luck

Comment: @nancy Did you figure out this?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but try installing font-awesome with NPM in the console, `npm install font-awesome` and then import them into your **app.scss;** `"@import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";`

Answer (score 0):

You can download, customize, and use the icons and default styling manually: [Download Link font-awesome Version 4.7.0](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip)

**Using CSS:**

1. Copy the entire **font-awesome** directory into your project.
2. In the `<head>` of your HTML, reference the location to your `font-awesome.min.css`.

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

More Info: [font-awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/get-started/)